# В какой момент применяется групповая функция с последующим присоединением другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, oracle

Предположим, есть запрос:

```
SELECT T1.COL_1,
       MIN(COL_1) 
  FROM TABLE_1 T1
    JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID like 'U%'
```

Вопрос: MIN(COL_1) будет искаться

- среди всех значений TABLE_1
- среди всех значений TABLE_1 с ID, начинающимся на U
- среди всех значений TABLE_1 с ID, начинающимся на U, которые есть в TABLE_2

Comment: По ходу я сочинил задачу для собеседования :)

Comment: А вы как думаете?

Comment: Третий вариант. (вроде)

Comment: А я бы предположил второй :)

Comment: Проверил на выборке из DUAL. Правильный второй вариант :3 Только T1.COL_1 нужно убрать, конечно.

Comment: Сначала построение набора данных (JOIN). Затем отбор (WHERE). Затем вычисление выходного набора (MIN). А на самом деле - ошибка по причине ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ещё на этапе синтаксического разбора.

Comment: У вас ошибка в заголовке -  "с последующим присоединением", а присоединяете вы второю таблицу сразу.

Comment: @0xdb Ну строка присоединения идет за строкой функции. А насчёт того кто выполняется первым и была суть вопроса

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов А, в этом смысле! В SQL не привычно считать, кто за кем идёт построчно, поэтому и понял не так. Соединение таблиц с соответствующими фильтрами всегда в первую очередь, аггрегатные функции на конечном rowset (иначе и смысла нет - они посчитают что то не то).